# struggling with sending data to another activity

Tags: java, android, oop

Ive been stressed out with trying to do this (im new to this). Im creating an app for android like cookie clicker and I have done 75% of it. 
I'm struggling with one thing. I have done the entire click on the button, it adds one to that main integer which is in this case, is the amount of cookies you have. 
I now want a thing where if you click on a button it will add lets say 5 to the amount of cookies every lets say 1 second. 
But this button is in a different activity and when its pressed I need to send that whole add 5 every 1 second thing to the main activity. I'm not quite sure but I thought I had to do this using object oriented stuff and I wasn't exactly sure where in the code to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `CookieCounter` singleton class for you.
Use `CookieCounter.getInstance().increaseCount(int amount)` to increase the count by `amount`. Use `CookieCounter.getInstance().getCount()` to get the current count.

```
public class CookieCounter {
    private static CookieCounter instance;
    int count = 0;
    public static CookieCounter getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new CookieCounter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public void increaseCount(int amount) {
        count += amount;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please explain the what the instance  is and what the constructor is doing

Comment: The instance is a varianle holding the actual CookieCounter object. The getInstance() method checks if the instance variable has been initialized and initializes a new CookieCounter if needed. Later calls to the getInstance() method always return the same CookieCounter object (stored in the instance variable). This way your Activities can use the same CookieCounter object.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `enum` to adopt the singleton pattern. It is thread-safe and more easy to implement:

```
public enum ClickerCounter {
HANDLER;

private int _count = 0;

public void increase(int amount) {
    _count += amount;
}

public int getCount() {
    return _count;
}

}
```

//Usage

```
ClickerCounter.HANDLER.getCount();
ClickerCounter.HANDLER.increase(value);
```